# Multiple Ajax Requests per MVC 4 View

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the repository pattern with a context and ninject as the IOC. I have a service which handles getting and setting page properties in the database.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base ("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<PageProperty> PageProperties { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultRepository : IRepository
{
    MyContext _context;
    public DefaultRepository(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<PageProperty> PageProperties { get { return _context.PageProperties; } }
    public IQueryable<Contact> Contacts { get { return _context.Contacts; } }
}

public class ModuleLoader : NinjectModule
{
    public ModuleLoader()
    {

    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        var context = new MyContext();
        context.Database.Initialize(false);
        Bind<MyContext>().ToConstant(context).InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IRepository>().To<DefaultRepository>();
        Bind<IPagePropertyProvider>().To<DefaultPagePropertyProvider>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}

public class DefaultPagePropertyProvider : IPagePropertyProvider
{
    IRepository _repository;
    object _syncLock = new object();

    public DefaultPagePropertyProvider (IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public string GetValue(string pageName, string propertyName
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            var prop = page.PageProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Property.Equals(propertyName) && x.PageName.Equals(pageName)).Value;

            return prop;
        }
     }
     public void SetValue(string pageName, string propertyName, string value)
     {
         var pageProp = _repository.PageProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Property.Equals(propertyName) && x.PageName.Equals(pageName));
         pageProp.Value = value;
         _repository.SaveSingleEntity(pageProp);
     }
}
```

In my view I am doing 3 ajax calls, one to get a list from contacts to fill out a table, one ajax call to determine how many pages i have depending on the page size I'm using, and one ajax call to set the page size that I want to use. so a select box changes the page size (How many contacts per page: [  30]) , a table that displays the contacts (generated from jquery which decifers json), and finally a div containing a list of page numbers to click. The workflow is, call `GetContacts()`, this function then queries the `PageProperties` to find out the page size to use, then call `GetPages()`, this function also queries `PageProperties` to find out what page size to use, `SetPageSize()` which sets the page size. So `GetContacts()` and `GetPages()` is used when a page is selected from the div, `SetPageSize()` then `GetContacts()` and `GetPages()` is called when the select box change event is fired. `GetContacts()` and `GetPages()` is only called when the first `SetPageSize()` `$.ajax` request is `done()` and there is a `success` from that function.

Now, before I added `lock(syncLock)` in the `DefaultPageProperty` service and before I added `InSingletonScope` to both that service and the context, I was getting two errors.

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
>
> An EdmType cannot be mapped to CLR classes multiple times

I assumed because the connection was in a `connecting` state, that the context was being reused and reused and reused, so I thought putting that to `SingletonScope()` would mean that only one connection was made, then I thought the same about `DefaultPageProperty` and then because I was making async calls to that service, I should put a lock over the database querying.

It works, and the problems don't exist. But I don't know if what I have done is correct within the pattern I'm using, I'm wondering if I've missed something fundamental? My question is, is this a proper/viable solution which won't create any caveats later down the road? Have I actually solved the issue or just created more?

Comment: you should post this on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You're using a `SingletonScope` with a service that creates a connection to your database. I believe all of the dependencies that are created by the singleton also become singleton by default...including your context. So you are always going to be using the same connection and never closing it.

Comment: So are you saying, if `MyContext` is in `SingletonScope()` then anything that use `MyContext` which is basically all my services, become `SingletonScope()` ?

Comment: @Malachi i have posted it on CodeReview, but stackoverflow gets more traffic!

Comment: I hear that, there isn't as much traffic there because not very many people post there. I am going to dedicate some time to Code Review for a while.  I would post in both places , but I think that might be against the rules.....From the MetaStack it looks like Cross Posting is Frowned upon but the posts are over 3 years old on that question. [is it necessary to be able to able to cross post between sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1535/is-it-necessary-to-be-able-to-cross-post-between-sites)

Comment: @No1_Melman No, what I'm saying is that anything that the singleton uses also becomes a singleton. You wouldn't want a database connection to be a singleton. What happens when it gets an error? I don't believe the connection automatically resets itself. It would be broken until you restarted the app pool.

Comment: @Dismissile ahh I see what you are saying, if I define the `MyContext` as `TransientScope()`, if my `SingletonScope()` service uses the `MyRepository` which uses the `MyContext` will that make `MyContext` become a `Singleton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redesigned the way I do my context now.

I have my context then I implement `IDbContextFactory<TContext>` called `DefaultContextFactory<MyContext>` and I inject them.

In the Repository I have in the public constructor `_context = contextFactory.Create();`.

Then throughout the repository i just use `_context.WhatEver()` and its fine.

I also did in the `ModuleLoader` `Bind<IRepository>().To<DefaultRepository>().InTransientScope()` in order to make every call to it create a new repository!

I don't need a repository factory because I only have one repository!